# Assignment Operator Overload Won't Work for my Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

Based on code already given to me, I overloaded the assignment operator so I can copy the elements of one array into another. Here's the function definition for the operator:

```
template<typename elemType>
const arrayListType<elemType>& arrayListType<elemType>::
        operator=(const arrayListType<elemType>& otherList) {
    if (this != &otherList) {
        delete[] list;
        maxSize = otherList.maxSize;
        length = otherList.length;

        list = new elemType[maxSize];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            list[i] = otherList.list[i];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

However, when I try to use the operator on two arrays, I get an error saying that the "expression must be a modifiable lvalue," and I am not sure why this error is showing up. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
int main() {
    unorderedArrayListType<float> floatList[25];
    float floatMember;
    unorderedArrayListType<int> intList[25];
    int intMember;
    unorderedArrayListType<float> otherFloatList[25] = { 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9, 10.10 };

    cout << "Enter 5 list members: " << endl; //floatList
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        cin >> floatMember;
        floatList->insertEnd(floatMember);
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "floatList: " << endl;
    floatList->print();
    cout << endl;
    ...
    floatList = otherFloatList;
    floatList->print();
    cout << endl;
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: I don't think this is what you meant to do: `unorderedArrayListType<float> otherFloatList[25] = { 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9, 10.10 };`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Um.... `unorderedArrayListType<float> floatList[25];` - did you really intend to declare an array of 25 `unorderedArrayListType<float>` objects ? Isn't the point of your `unorderedArrayListType<float>` that *it* is the "array" ? if not, don't do that. And if you did, then `floatList = otherFloatList;` is no more valid than `int a[5], b[5]; a = b;` . Arrays are not assignable lvalues.

Comment: presumably `unorderedArrayListType<float> floatList[25];` -> `unorderedArrayListType<float> floatList{25};`

Comment: Tangential: It's a bit strange for `operator=` to return a `const` reference instead of a non-`const` reference.

Comment: @WhozCraig I meant to create an array with a maximum size of 25; not all of the 25 spaces in memory are filled, I just wanted to make it that way to account for extra space if I needed it. Also, I'm required to test the assignment operator with arrays.

Comment: I understand, but it doesn't change what I said. You seem to want an `unorderedArrayList<float>` that can hold 25 elements; *not* an array of 25 `unorderedArrayList<float>` objects. There is an obvious difference. Your assignment operator acts on instances of `unorderedArrayList<float>`. But your code is not using your assignment operator; it is trying to copy one **native** array to another **native** array using copy-assignment `=` . The language does not allow that. As I said, it is as non-legal as `int a[5], b[5]; a = b;`.